# Given a start time of a slot in 12hrs time format (say "2: 45 PM") and a period in mins after this ends 15 for eg. How would you calculate end time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, time

I have a date slot in string (12hrs) format eg - "2:45 PM" and a time period to when this slot ends say 15 (mins). So time slots starts at "2: 45 PM" and ends in 15 mins. I want to show the ending time in the same format as time string in 12hrs format.

Example - Slot: "2: 45 PM", ends: 15
endingSlot will be "3: 00 PM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a library for that — e.g. [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

const slot = '2.45 PM';
const endingSlot = moment(slot, 'h:mm A').add(15, 'minutes').format('h:mm A');

console.log(endingSlot); // 3:00 PM
```